# Vote on Synonyms!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We have a number of suggested [tag synonyms](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested) which are pending:

```
Master             Synonym
code-coverage      test-coverage
code-coverage      coverage
visual-workflow    flow
salesforce1-app    sf1
formula            formula-field
soql               query
locking            lock-record
visualforce        page
validation         validation-rule
string             string-methods
```

I have actually changed my mind about `[query]` and `[formula-field]`, as I think the generic umbrella tags of `[query]`, `[formula]`, and `[validation]` do have value on their own, separate from the more specific tags of `[soql]`, `[formula-field]`, and `[validation-rule]`. As such, I have voted against the `[validation]` synonym, though I cannot vote against the other two, since I proposed them.

If you have an opinion one way or another, go vote! Some of these synonyms have been pending votes for over a year now!

Feel free to post comments or answers debating the merits of any of these synonyms, or any you think should be added, if you do not have the rep to do so yourself.

---

We're actually almost through them! There are three tags left to vote on. We need one more vote against for each to kill the synonyms on [`[soql]`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/soql/synonyms) and [`[formula]`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/formula/synonyms). We need three more votes in favor to approve that for [`[locking]`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/locking/synonyms).

Comment: Might be because I'm still recovering from working a 23-hour shift Tues-Wed, but I was having trouble finding where to vote on synonyms. From the tag synonyms page that Adrian linked, I needed to click on the 'master' tag to be able to vote on the synonym.

Comment: @DerekF good point, added links in the OP. Get some rest!

Comment: Also, looks like most of the suggested synonyms have been cleared up. Nice call to action.

Comment: Master: lightning-design-system Synonym: slds I don't have 2500 rep yet : )

Comment: Good luck finding enough people around who have sufficient points to be able to vote on the `[locking]` synonym!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I can unilaterally approve/reject synonyms. I will not do this for any controversial tags, but for really obvious ones it makes the issue a bit simpler, especially when we don't have a ton of users with enough tag points to vote. We're down to just one suggested synonym now, which I felt was less obvious: `[page-layout]` (master) and `[layout]` (synonym).

Let me know if you take issue with any of these decisions and I will happily revisit.